# Scope of a variable in PHP

Tags: php, global-variables

I have the following file:

```
<?php
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/pages/destinations/europe/spain/abama.php');

    $location = $location . ", Spain";

    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/pages/destinations/hotel.php');
?>
```

The first includes is a file which contains the variable `$location = "Abama";`

The second includes displays html, using the variable `$location`.

However, currently the page is displaying with $location equalling *Abama*, as set in the first includes. It should be *Abama*, Spain as set on the main page (above).

I've tried adding `global($location)` to both include pages and the main page, but when I do an `echo $location` after I have altered the location on the main page it returns the correct variable.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: need to show code that's setting it in the other places, and code that's displaying it

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. Echo'ed result was `Abama, Spain` so it's obviously something in your `abama.php` file that's playing tricks on you.